# Corner and edge detection in a graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I am at the moment trying to program a corner and edge detecting scheme which  should be capable of detecting corners and edges in a graph.

The graph data structure is built from a 2d char array which could look like this Size of this example is 10 rows and 9 col. (White spaces fill in the rest of the missing, I could not add whitespace at the borders...?)

```
      ...
 ..Y.....
 ..Y   .
  ZYZ.Z.Z
  .Y ....
  .M
  ..
```

A node is created for each character in the node, and the complete graph is stored as a `vector<Node> graph`.

Each node is defined as such

```
struct Node
{
    char character;
    pair<int,int> position;
    bool lock;
    vector<Vertex> adjacent;
};

struct Vertex
{
   Node *current;
   Node *nextTo;

};
```

So.. I have a lot nodes but some of them is redundant in my use case, for which each node has a `bool lock` => telling the systems that these nodes should be ignored.

The nodes i want to ignore are those which has the character `.`, in the map and  is placed at a corner position (the node itself has 2 neighbor (the size vector neighbour == 2)), or nodes with character `.` which is between two corners.  If other character occurs between two corners will only the corners be set locked. while traversing adjacent node of the corner ( looking for the second corner), and a node has 4 adjacent node,will only the first corner seen be set to be locked.

So..I wrote it into some code which ended up look like this.

```
 for(auto graph_it = begin(graph); graph_it != end(graph); graph_it++)
    {
        if(graph_it->adjacent.size() == 2 && graph_it->character == '.')
        {
            vector<Node*> trace;
            cout << "corner found " <<"("<< graph_it->position.first <<","<< graph_it->position.second << ")" << endl;
            graph_it->lock = true;

            for (Vertex edge : graph_it->adjacent)
            {
                cout << "Check neighbour direction" << endl;
                int changeX = 0;
                int changeY = 0;

                changeX = graph_it->position.first - edge.nextTo->position.first;
                changeY = graph_it->position.second - edge.nextTo->position.second;

                cout << "neighbour direction is first: " << changeX << changeY << endl;
                auto start_position = edge.nextTo;
                vector<Node*> trace;
                bool endIsCorner = false;
                bool conditionMet = false;
                cout << endl;
                while((start_position->adjacent.size() != 2|| start_position->adjacent.size() != 4) /*&& start_position->character =='.'*/)
                {
                    for(Vertex traversing_edge : start_position->adjacent)
                    {
                        cout <<"position before: " << graph_it->position.first << graph_it->position.second << " now position: "<< start_position->position.first << start_position->position.second <<  " change is: " << (start_position->position.first - traversing_edge.nextTo->position.first) <<  " " << start_position->position.second - traversing_edge.nextTo->position.second  << " character is: " << traversing_edge.nextTo->character << endl;
                        if (traversing_edge.nextTo->adjacent.size() == 2)
                        {
                            cout << "error found case 1" << endl;
                            cout << "position: " << traversing_edge.nextTo->character << traversing_edge.nextTo->position.first << traversing_edge.nextTo->position.second << endl;
                            start_position = traversing_edge.nextTo;
                            start_position->lock =true;
                            trace.push_back(start_position);
                            endIsCorner = true;
                            conditionMet = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if(traversing_edge.nextTo->adjacent.size() == 4)
                        {
                            cout << "error found case 2" << endl;
                            cout << "position: " << traversing_edge.nextTo->character << traversing_edge.nextTo->position.first << traversing_edge.nextTo->position.second << endl;
                            conditionMet = true;
                            break;
                        }

                        if (start_position->position.first - traversing_edge.nextTo->position.first  == changeX && start_position->position.second - traversing_edge.nextTo->position.second == changeY)
                        {
                            if (traversing_edge.nextTo->adjacent.size() == 3 )
                            {
                                start_position = traversing_edge.nextTo;
                                cout << "traversed to position: " << start_position->position.first << start_position->position.second <<" character: "<<start_position->character<< endl;
                                trace.push_back(start_position);
                            }

                            if (traversing_edge.nextTo->adjacent.size() == 2)
                            {
                                edge.nextTo->lock = true;
                                start_position = traversing_edge.nextTo;
                                cout << "traversed to position being corner: " << start_position->position.first << start_position->position.second <<" character: "<<start_position->character<< endl;
                                trace.push_back(start_position);
                                endIsCorner = true;
                            }

                            if (traversing_edge.nextTo->adjacent.size() == 4)
                            {
                                cout << "traversed something else: " << start_position->position.first << start_position->position.second <<" character: "<<start_position->character<< endl;
                                start_position = traversing_edge.nextTo;
                            }
                        }
                        cout << endl;
                    }
                    if (conditionMet)
                    {
                        break;/* code */
                    }

                }
                if (endIsCorner == true)
                {
                    for(auto traced: trace)
                    {
                        cout << "Traced for locking position: " <<traced->position.first << traced->position.second << traced->character<< endl;
                        if (traced->character == '.')
                        {
                            cout << "locking position: " <<traced->position.first << traced->position.second << traced->character<< endl;
                            traced->lock = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    trace.empty();
                    endIsCorner = false;
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }

        }
        cout << endl;
    }

  cout << "Locks detected" << endl;
```

As I realized the code didn't do as I want it to do, I began debugging it..

So the first weird thing i saw is this. The first node it detects as a corner is the one located at row 2 and col 1, which is correct.

It  then tries to traverse in the direction of the first nextTo node direction which is the one under it (row 3 , col 2)  which is also a corner, but somehow it enters while loop? which i don't get. Its adjacent vector size is 2, which the debugger also say, but somehow within the while loop it detects the size being 2, and gets out of the while loop correctly and set it that node to be locked.... (Possible issue)

As i fininsh all this, I check the full graph to see if  the things that should be locked is also locked... which isn't the case.

```
for(auto node :  graph)
{    
    cout << "node position: " <<"(" << node.position.first << "," << node.position.second << ")" << " " << node.character << endl;   
    if (node.locked)
    {
      cout << node.position.first << node.position.second << endl;
    }
}
```

For which i get this output

```
node position: (2,1) .
21
node position: (3,1) .
31
node position: (2,2) .
node position: (3,2) .
node position: (4,2) Z
node position: (5,2) .
52
node position: (6,2) .
node position: (7,2) .
72
node position: (2,3) Y
node position: (3,3) Y
node position: (4,3) Y
node position: (5,3) Y
node position: (6,3) M
node position: (7,3) .
73
node position: (2,4) .
24
node position: (4,4) Z
node position: (2,5) .
25
node position: (4,5) .
node position: (5,5) .
55
node position: (1,6) .
16
node position: (2,6) .
node position: (4,6) Z
node position: (5,6) .
node position: (1,7) .
node position: (2,7) .
node position: (3,7) .
37
node position: (4,7) .
node position: (5,7) .
57
node position: (1,8) .
18
node position: (2,8) .
28
node position: (4,8) Z
48
node position: (5,8) .
58
```

Meaning that it locks not only those i want it to lock (being character `.` which i placed at the specified location) but also those i don't want to lock (characters other than `.`).

```
(5,2) should not be locked
(2,4) should not be locked
(2,5) should not be locked
(1,7) should be locked
(4,7) should be locked
```

What is going wrong here.. I am pretty sure that it must have to do with the issue i found in my debugger, but i do not understand why that even occurs at all?

---Update--

I seem to have found another issue as seen here.

```
corner found (7,2)
Check neighbour direction
neighbour direction is first: 10

position before:  72 now position: 62 change is: 1 0 Element is: .
traversed in right direction . 
traversed to position: 52 Element: .

position before:  72   now position: 52 change is: -2 0 Element is: .
error found case 1
position: .72
```

This is outputted from the while loop.

```
while((start_position->adjacent.size() != 2|| start_position->adjacent.size() != 4) /*&& start_position->character =='.'*/)
                    {
                        for(Vertex traversing_edge : start_position->adjacent)
                        { .. }
```

I change the value of the `start_position` within the `for` loop,  how will the loop react on that?..  In my head it should start all over, and start from the beginning, instead of continuing iterating the first start_position vector.

Should it be a `while` instead an `for`?

`Start_position` starts by being the node placed at (7,2), then it traverse to the node to the right (6,2), and that becomes the new `start_position`. Then it traverses to the right again (5,2) and `start_position` becomes that node. But the the variable `traversing_edge` becomes the node placed at (7,2) and thereby end incorrectly..  `traversing_edge` becomes an impossible value, as the nodes neighbouring the node placed at (5,2) only has the neighbours (4,2),(6,2) ,(5,3)... So something definitely wrong here..

--Update --

```
      DDD
 D.Y....D
 D.Y   .
  ZYZ.Z.Z
  .Y DDDD
  .M
  DD
```

No Nodes has a adjacent vector of size 1, nodes with whitespace chars is also created.  `D` shows which nodes should be locked.

**--- Lamda update ---**

Its a sokoban map, and M is the person, and Y is the diamond and Z are goals. The idea is that M pushes Y in a certain direction, but to prevent moving the diamond to a position where it cannot be retrieved again, will this scheme preprocess the graph such that those position will be ignored.

Comment: Is `struct Vertex` supposed to be `struct Edge`? Not a solution -- I just got confused seeing `Vertex` here and `Edge` there.

Comment: yes.. I fixed the issue.

I tried to make the post a bit more understandable by only inserting the relevant part rather the of the whole code.. But it seems i messed up a bit.. 
But `Struct Vertex` = `Struct Edge`.  It should be removed now.

Comment: Apologies -- haven't been so helpful yet. Could you post the desired kind of ASCII art output after processing the input? I want to make sure I understand what constitutes a corner and edge correctly.

Comment: Added.. Atleast you are trying.. that is more than what I had expected :)

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why `[3,1] and [3,2]` aren't considered a corner -- as it has two neighbors (the two dots to the right of the `Y`). Another one: [6,2] (stranded dot). Does the notion of "neighbor" span diagonally? It doesn't seem like it, since then nothing would have exactly 2 neighbors.

Comment: Could you mark then on the asci graph.. 
The idea with a lock is to find position where i can't push items to that position without having it stuck there, and not be able to retrieve it again.

Comment: Apologies -- I appended on the bottom what I meant in your post through an edit -- hope you don't mind. I couldn't find a way to communicate this through the comments.

Comment: Its a sokoban map, and M is the person, and Y is the diamond and Z are goals. The idea is that M pushes Y in a certain direction, but to prevent moving the diamond to position where it cannot be retrieved again, will this scheme preprocess the graph such that those position will be ignored. thats why yours map is not true.. I might have missed some points, but I hope you understand the use case of this scheme, and how it should preprocess the graph... Which is also why i will updated your edit with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95811/discussion-between-lamda-and-ike).

Comment: Sorry, I won't go through all the code right now, but how about changing the approach a bit: Write a function, that takes a single node as parameter and decides only for this node, whether it should be locked. First ensure correct functionality, then just apply the function to each node.

Comment: I think you are right about separating the code, and give it more structure is needed. The debugger is very useful for debugging, but tracking multiple variables makes it impossible to track.

Comment: Well the debugger can perfectly track a large number of changes to a large number of variables. The problem is your (and everyone elses) brain, thats not made to have more than 4-7 concurrent isses tracked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. I finally managed to solve my problem, by rewriting it..

The new version work in a different way, and seem a bit more structured for the human eye, but slower compared the one posted above.

I am certain that i've also found the error in my code above. 
My over usage of range based for loops, made it impossible to insert an value on the member value of the object, which the debugger showed me..

Fixing that and some other things would have made it work.

I want to thank everyone for trying to help solve my problem, your help was very much appreciated. I didn't think people would react on such a long post, but I felt at the same time I had to provide all the given information so if anyone dared to look into it,they would have reasonable chance of understanding it..

thanks :)

Comment: Congratulations on solving your problem. Regarding the 'long' question: it is always best to limit your question to the shortest complete example that shows your actual problem. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve but the 'complete' part is just as important as the 'minimal'. In your case, I guess noone really read your code in details, but it still helped me seeing your underlying design problems.